# Understanding these assembly instructions

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers

I'm learning assembly by writing C programs and viewing the assembly output. I've included the C program at the bottom for the page to make it easier. I'm struggling to understand one line of assembly:

cdqe

movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-32+rax] <--- what is this doing?

movsx   eax, al

So I think cdqe extends eax into rax (64 bits). Its clear that the string I want to print fits into the al register but I don't understand what is happening deep down with rbp-32+rax. Can someone explain for me?

```
.file   "string_manip.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello"
    .string ""
    .zero   3
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    sub rsp, 48
    mov rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
    mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
    xor eax, eax
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 0
    mov eax, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-32], eax
    movzx   eax, WORD PTR .LC0[rip+4]
    mov WORD PTR [rbp-28], ax
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR .LC0[rip+6]
    mov BYTE PTR [rbp-26], al
    mov WORD PTR [rbp-25], 0
    mov BYTE PTR [rbp-23], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 0
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-36]
    cdqe
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-32+rax] <--- what is this doing?
    movsx   eax, al
    mov edi, eax
    call    putchar
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 1
.L2:
    cmp DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 5
    jle .L3
    mov edi, 10
    call    putchar
    mov eax, 0
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    xor rdx, QWORD PTR fs:40
    je  .L5
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L5:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits


#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char array[10] = "Hello\0";
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        printf("%c", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it zero-extends (unsigned upcast) the byte pointed by `rbp-32+rax` and moves it into eax; think something like `uint32_t eax = *(uint8_t *)(rbp - 32 + rax);`

Comment: You will have a better time reading compiler output at `-Og -fverbose-asm`.  `-O0` is way too noisy (with stores and re-loads all over the place).  You have to follow all the data movement to see if it's the same variable being re-loaded, or a different variable.  I'd rather look at `-O3` output to "see what the compiler did", but I already know asm and the only thing of interest to me is seeing if the compiler found of any clever optimizations that I didn't. :P  But seriously, if you know what compilers usually do, you can follow optimized code.  `-Og` is by far the best for learning, or O1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just calculating the address of one of the characters.

Presumably your string starts at `rbp-32` and then the instruction does the C equivalent of `ch = string[rax]`.

I guess this is unoptimized code, so the compiler does a few extra sign extend and zero extend that are not really needed.

Comment: Yes the string does start at rbp-32 but I was wondering why its necessary for the +rax part of the rbp-32+rax. If the string starts at rbp-32 can we not just use that? Thank you for the "calculating address of characters", sums it up nicely

Comment: There seems to be a loop at `.L2` that increments something and goes back to `.L3`. Also, as this looks like unoptimized C, the assembly code does lots of things that the optimizer would reduce. Like use a single pointer to the string, and increment the pointer instead of incrementing an index. And perhaps keep everything in registers in the loop.